# How do I capture all occurences in a string in Vim?

Tags: regex, string, vim, replace, capture

I want to capture all certain occurrences in a string in Vimscript.

example:

```
let my_calculation = '200/3 + 23 + 100.5/3 -2 + 4*(200/2)'
```

How can I capture all numbers (including dots if there are) before and after the '/'? in 2 different variables:
- output before_slash: 200100.5200
- output after slash 332

How can I replace them if a condition occurs?
p.e. if after a single '/' there is no '.' add '.0' after this number

I tried to use matchstring and regex but after trying and trying I couldn't resolve it.

Comment: maybe it will help you `my $str = '200/3 + 23 + 100.5/3 -2 + 4*(200/2)';
@pair = ($str=~m/(\d+)\/(\d+)/g); 
my $left = "";
my $right = "";
while(@pair){
      $left.=shift @pair;
      $right.=shift @pair;
}
`

perl code, just need some checks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the second part of the question:

```
let my_calculation = '200/3 + 23 + 100.5/3 -2 + 4*(200/2)'
echo substitute(my_calculation, '\(\/[0-9]\+\)\([^0-9.]\|$\)', '\1.0\2', 'g')
```

The above outputs:

```
200/3.0 + 23 + 100.5/3.0 -2 + 4*(200/2.0)
```

Answer (score 3):

A useful feature that can be taken advantage of in this case is substitution
with an expression (see `:help sub-replace-\=`).

```
let [a; b] = [[]]
call substitute(s, '\(\d*\.\?\d\+\)/\(\d*\.\?\d\+\)\zs',
\   '\=add(a,submatch(1))[1:0]+add(b,submatch(2))[1:0]', 'g')
```

Comment: @Remonn:  Lists containing captured numerators and denominators, correspondingly.

Comment: Very nice regex. I will remember it. It found the solution of Creemama useful to do the substitution I asked in my question, but I suppose it will be possible also with your regex.

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try:

```
function! GetNumbers(string)
  let pairs = filter(split(a:string, '[^0-9/.]\+'), 'v:val =~ "/"')
  let den = join(map(copy(pairs), 'matchstr(v:val, ''/\zs\d\+\(\.\d\+\)\?'')'), '')
  let num = join(map(pairs, 'matchstr(v:val, ''\d\+\(\.\d\+\)\?\ze/'')'), '')
  return [num, den]
endfunction
let my_calculation = '200/3 + 23 + 100.5/3 -2 + 4*(200/2)'
let [a,b] = GetNumbers(my_calculation)
echo a
echo b
```